# Unsustained Interference Visuals

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, interference, coherence

How does the interference (of coherent EM waves) that is not sustained look like? Kindly provide me with pictures or visual description. I tried searching the web but no avail.

People say fluctuations of fringes will be observed... But won't those fluctuations be too fast for human eyes to observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done and the gif below a movie recorded with the CCTV camera with subtracted background slowed is proof.

[image]

An experimental proof that two independent light beams can form an interference pattern was first demonstrated in 1963 by Mandel and Magyar and described in [Interference of Light Beams from Two Independent Lasers](http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/LaserInterference/LaserInterference.html) which also has a reference to the original paper.

The scale of the problem is as follows.
If two HeNe laser sources with 632nm wavelengths with a difference of .001% in frequency, the fringes would oscillate at 47GHz.  If this fringe was to be viewed by the unaided eye then it would only see the time average of the intensity at every point in space, which would appear as a blur of light instead of fringes.  In addition the phase relationship between the two laser must also remain relatively constant. If the fringes move quickly with change in time they appear as a blur of light.
To produce stable fringes that are visible by the unaided eye the two wave packets traveling to the observer must be coherent (same frequency, constant phase relation) for the integration time of the eye, which is around .02 seconds.  This would mean that the difference in frequency of the two photon sources would have to be less than 50Hz. [Jiefei Wang - Interference of Separate Photons by Two Independent Lasers](http://www.u.arizona.edu/%7Ejiefeiw/final.htm)

If two independent light sources are used potential problems may well occur because of the frequency difference of the lasers and the fact that the laser might be producing several different frequencies and that a supposed single frequency emitted by a laser is actually a range of frequencies.

In the paper [Observation of two truly independent laser interference made easy](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6404/ac0877/pdf), the origin of the first gif, the lowest frequency difference between the lasers was about $100\,\rm kHz$ and to obtain high quality images a camera with exposure time less than  $1,\rm μs was used.
I do like the phrase *. . . . made easy* which shows the progress that has been made in this field since the time in the 1930s when Paul Dirac stated that *interference between two different photons never occurs.*
The paper by Tomasz Kawalec and Piotr Sowa has a comprehensive list of reference and there is some supplementary data.
[Observation of two truly independent laser interference made easy – Technical Details](https://cfn-live-content-bucket-iop-org.s3.amazonaws.com/journals/0143-0807/42/5/055305/revision3/EJPac0877supp4.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYDKQL6LTV7YY2HIK&Expires=1675585675&Signature=5FxdG%2BiEx52YMhr3l%2FWFD%2Fje9h0%3D)
A typical movie recorded with the CCTV camera with subtracted background, with
a native frame rate as well as slowed down three times, ([CCTV_30fps.gif](https://cfn-live-content-bucket-iop-org.s3.amazonaws.com/journals/0143-0807/42/5/055305/revision3/EJPac0877supp3.gif?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYDKQL6LTV7YY2HIK&Expires=1675585675&Signature=LD8C5aGFTZ82%2BFz3d%2FU3zXrt1VU%3D) and
[CCTV_10fps.gif](https://cfn-live-content-bucket-iop-org.s3.amazonaws.com/journals/0143-0807/42/5/055305/revision3/EJPac0877supp2.gif?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYDKQL6LTV7YY2HIK&Expires=1675585675&Signature=VlQrTtnNv4utSxDDMxuKHSJHFE4%3D), respectively.
A short movie consisting of five post-selected frames with an interference pattern recorded for two He–Ne lasers in the single AOM configuration, seen both in 1 st (left spot) and 2 nd (right spot) AOM diffraction order [1st_and_2nd_order.gif](https://cfn-live-content-bucket-iop-org.s3.amazonaws.com/journals/0143-0807/42/5/055305/revision3/EJPac0877supp1.gif?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYDKQL6LTV7YY2HIK&Expires=1675585675&Signature=ThdQNDxyqkVwPlQ24CsB4eAM7JQ%3D).

Comment: Thanks for such a descriptive answer.